# Select string in between two strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to output a string in between two strings. The problem is sometimes one of the two reference strings will be missing. If the first reference string is not missing and the second reference string is missing, I want to output from the first reference string to the end of the string. If the first reference string is missing, I want to output null or blank.

I saw a similar post but it included the reference strings. In my case, I do not want to include the reference strings.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('1stRefStr', @Text)
, CHARINDEX('2ndRefStr',@text) - CHARINDEX('1stRefStr', @Text) + Len('2ndRefStr'))
```

```
Example:
Patient: A Date: 1/1/1 Message: Hi Message Sent To: B
```

```
1st string reference is "Message:"
2nd string reference is "Message Sent To:"
```

```
Expected Result:
Hi
```

Comment: Please make your example more clear.  What parts comprise string1 and string2?  You mention getting 2 different outputs based on string1 being null or not null, but you only give 1 example.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention 1st string is Message: and 2nd string is Message Sent To: will edit my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with? How do you expect to find the substring without using the delimiters? And why do you have such a mess for your data in the first place?

Comment: SQL version is 2016. I dont know why the data is setup that way I just output the data and give reports based on them; I wasnt the one who setup the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a helper function.

Being a TVF, it is easy to incorporate into a CROSS APPLY if your data is in a table.

I modified a split/parse function to accept two non-like delimeters.

**Example**

```
Declare @Text varchar(max) = 'Patient: A Date: 1/1/1 Message: Hi Message Sent To: B'

Select *
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@Text,'Message:','Message Sent') A
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       Hi
```

**The Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1
)
```

Update As A CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'Patient: A Date: 1/1/1 Message: Hi Message Sent To: B')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
                      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex('Message Sent',RetVal)-1)
                 From  (
                         Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                               ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                          From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'Message:','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
                          Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) C1
                 Where charindex('Message Sent',RetVal)>1
             ) B
```

Comment: Idk why this is downvoted. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ReportWriter Happy to help

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to do this without creating a function?

Comment: @ReportWriter sure.  Give me a moment

Comment: @ReportWriter Is your data in a table, or are you processing individual strings

Comment: @ReportWriter See Update or take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=39ee2396a0ae7dddf988d134f1bf06a1

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again!